# PYTHON change datetime.date.today()

Tags: python, datetime, metatrader5

Currently when using `datetime.date.today()` the today's date is returned as YYYY-MM-DD I would like to return it as YYYY,MM,DD as I would like to automate the date that is used in the MT5 copy rates function

```
mt5.copy_rates_from(EURUSD, mt5.TIMEFRAME_H4, yyyy,mm,dd, 200)
```

I would like to calculate the date with out having to manually type it in but if I use `datetime.date.today()` the code does not work.

Automate the date with out manually typing it in.

Comment: `datetime.date.today()` returns an object of the type `datetime.date` and not a string with the format "YYYY-MM-DD". Look at the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method of the returned object.

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html, especially with the `format` string, e.g. `dt.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")`

Answer (score 0):

You can get year, month, and day separately by using the method [timetuple()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple) of date. The function, however, returns a tuple with 9 items. You can get the first three by doing:

```
yyyy, mm, dd = datetime.date.today().timetuple()[:3]
```

`[:3]` means the first three values of the list. Each variable is assigned to the corresponding value of the list.

The values are returned as `ints`, not strings.